# Writing a test function leveraging two namespaces in lisp

Tags: scheme, lisp, common-lisp, funcall

I started to learn Lisp and using Lispworks personal edition 6.1.1 and I hit on problem when evaluating basic functions. I am able to get them right in Scheme but they are not working when I try to evaluate them in Lisp.

I know in Lisp that every symbol has two namespaces. So I tried to write simple procedure for composing two procedures. It is working perfectly in Scheme but in Lisp there is a problem with evaluation.

Code in scheme it is working perfectly and return 2

```
(define (comp a b)
  (lambda (x)
    (a (b x))))

(define test (comp car cdr))
(test '(1 2 3))
```

Same code rewritten in Lisp

```
(defun comp (a b)
  (lambda (x)
    (funcall a (funcall b x))))

(defun test (comp #'car #'cdr))

(funcall test '(1 2 3))
```

Error in lispworks is:

> Trying to bind a non-symbol, `(FUNCTION CAR)`.

so when I try to evaluate `(defun test (comp #'car #'cdr))` in listener I get

> Non-symbol `(FUNCTION CAR)` used as variable name in function `TEST`.

I do not understand why it is not working written like that. I would aprreciate any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`defun` is used to define a function with parameters:

```
defun function-name lambda-list [[declaration* | documentation]] form*
```

so it requires a lambda list after the function name, but you have written:

```
(defun test (comp #'car #'cdr))
```

which does not respect this syntax. If you want to define a variable that contains the function resulting from composing two functions you have several possibilities:

1. Use a special variable:

   ```
   (defvar test (comp #'car #'cdr))
   ```
2. Use a local variable inside a form:

   ```
   (let ((test (comp #'car #'cdr)))
     (funcall test '(1 2 3))
   ```

You can even assign it to a global function name, like in:

```
(setf (symbol-function 'test) (comp #'car #'cdr)
```

and in this case you can use the name as a regular function name, without `funcall`:

```
(test '(1 2 3))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
(defun test (comp #'car #'cdr))
```

[`DEFUN`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/m_defun.htm) expects a lambda-list after the name, and here your lambda-list is malformed since `#'car` is not a symbol but reads as `(function car)`.

What you probably wanted to do is to define the function `test` as the composition of `car` and `cdr`; `(comp ...)` would return the appropriate function object but `defun` does not allow to have a value in place of the lambda-list.

You could do:

```
(setf (symbol-function 'test)
      (comp #'car #'cdr))
```

Answer (score 1):

With local functions:

```
CL-USER 1 > (flet ((comp (a b)
                     (lambda (x)
                       (funcall a (funcall b x)))))
              (let ((test (comp #'car #'cdr)))
                (flet ((test (x)
                         (funcall test x)))
                  (test '(1 2 3)))))
2

CL-USER 2 > (labels ((comp (a b)
                       (lambda (x)
                         (funcall a (funcall b x))))
                     (test (x)
                       (funcall (comp #'car #'cdr) x)))
              (test '(1 2 3)))
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion:

```
(defun comp (a b)
  (lambda (x)
     (funcall a (funcall b x))))

(defun mytest (x &key test)  ;; a "test" key is common
   (funcall test x))

(mytest '(1 2 3) :test (comp #'car #'cdr))
```

or

```
(defun comp (x a b)
  (funcall a (funcall b x)))

(defun test (x a b)
  (comp x a b))

(test '(1 2 3) #'car #'cdr)
```